# TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=[0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Im getting an error as

```
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

Comment: can you tell us what this `X` contains?

Comment: Here X is an dataset which contains country name and age

Comment: can you share one complete row?

Comment: @Damzaky here it is

Comment: Country Age Salary Purchased 
France 44 72000 No 
Spain 27 48000 Yes 
Germany 30 54000 No 
Spain 38 61000 No 
Germany 40  Yes 
France 35 58000 Yes 
Spain  52000 No 
France 48 79000 Yes 
Germany 50 83000 No 
France 37 67000 Yes

Comment: Please don't post relevant information about the question in the comments. You should [edit] the question to include it. See also what makes a proper [mre].